# Chromium --window-size and --window-position in kiosk mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, chromium, kiosk

I need to do a script that execute about 9 chromium browsers in kiosk mode with 9 different graphics to be monitored.

I'm trying to execute the following command line (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS):

```
chromium-browser --app={link} --window-size=x,y --window-position=x,y --kiosk
```

When it is executed without `--kiosk` parameter the `window-size` and `window-position` works fine, but when I try to execute with `--kiosk` it runs in full screen.

I tried to change the position of `--kiosk` and the window parameters but it not worked too. I also tryed to change in ".../chromium/Default/Preferences" the `window_placement` and `app_window_placement` maximized property to `false` instead `true` [Default].

My question is, is there some way to run chromium in `--kiosk` mode with my options of window size and position?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is an old question, anyway, "kiosk mode" means maximized (= to be run as a TV inside a kiosk). What you want is something else, similar to kiosk mode, i.e. without title bar and tabs bar

Comment: @luca.vercelli, do you have an example of that "something else"?

Answer (score 2):

```sh
chromium --app=https://youtube.com --window-size=1024,720 --window-position=450,150
```

Comment: That would not work with "--kiosk" option. window size and window-position are both ignored.

Comment: @mb3_48900 `--kiosk` with `--window-size` and `--window-position` works for me. I'm guessing there has been an update in the last year.

Comment: @nullromo It doesn't work for me on Windows 10. What system are you on? I can't find an option that respects `--window-size=1024,720 --window-position=450,150` and also hides the adress bar and the rest of the normal window UI.

Comment: I was using this on custom Raspbian.